# Put angle symbol between segments

Tags: tikz-pgf, arc, angle

I'm not sure how to put the angle arc symbol between the segments 'pm' and 'pz' in this figure I'm making:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,intersections,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3, mydot/.style={fill, circle, inner sep=1.5pt},every 
node/.style={font=\Large},>={Latex[length=3mm]}, decoration={markings, mark=at position 
0.6 with {\arrow{latex}}}]

\node[mydot] at (2.3,-2) {};

\tkzDefPoints{0/0/O, 5/0/M, 0/-1/A, 0/-2/B, 0/-3/C, 0/-4/D, 5/-1/S1, 5/-2/S2, 5/-3/S3}

\tkzDrawLine[add=0 and 0](O,D)
\tkzDrawLine[add=0 and 0](O,M)
\tkzDrawLine[add=0 and 0](A,S1)
\tkzDrawLine[add=0 and 0](B,S2)
\tkzDrawLine[add=0 and 0](C,S3)

\tkzLabelPoint[right](M){{\Large $M$}}
\tkzLabelPoint[right](S1){{\Large $S_{t_1}$}}
\tkzLabelPoint[right](S2){{\Large $S_{t}$}}
\tkzLabelPoint[right](S3){{\Large $S_{t_z}$}}

\draw[very thick,name path=Xp] (.3,-1.2) .. controls +(-3:1) and +(150:.2) .. (2.3,-2) 
.. controls +(-45:1) and +(178:1) .. (4.7,-2.8);

\draw[very thick,-latex,postaction={decorate},shorten >= 3pt] (2.3,-2) .. controls + 
(270:1) and +(90:1) .. (2.3,-2.9);
\draw[very thick,-latex,shorten >= 3pt] (2.3,-2) .. controls +(210:0) and +(20:0) .. 
(1.7,-2.6);

\node at (2.34,-1.9) {$p$};
\node at (2.45,-2.9) {$m$};
\node at (2.45,-2.5) {$\partial_t$};
\node at (1.65,-2.6) {$z$};
\node at (4.7,-2.65) {$S$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've redrawn the non-tkz-euclide part of your picture to simplify things and to draw the angle.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,intersections,arrows.meta,angles,quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3, mydot/.style={fill, circle, inner sep=1.5pt},every 
node/.style={font=\Large},>={Latex[length=3mm]}, decoration={markings, mark=at position 
0.6 with {\arrow{latex}}}]

\node[mydot] at (2.3,-2) {};

\tkzDefPoints{0/0/O, 5/0/M, 0/-1/A, 0/-2/B, 0/-3/C, 0/-4/D, 5/-1/S1, 5/-2/S2, 5/-3/S3}

\tkzDrawLine[add=0 and 0](O,D)
\tkzDrawLine[add=0 and 0](O,M)
\tkzDrawLine[add=0 and 0](A,S1)
\tkzDrawLine[add=0 and 0](B,S2)
\tkzDrawLine[add=0 and 0](C,S3)

\tkzLabelPoint[right](M){{\Large $M$}}
\tkzLabelPoint[right](S1){{\Large $S_{t_1}$}}
\tkzLabelPoint[right](S2){{\Large $S_{t}$}}
\tkzLabelPoint[right](S3){{\Large $S_{t_z}$}}

\draw[very thick,name path=Xp] (.3,-1.2) .. controls +(-3:1) and +(150:.2) .. (2.3,-2) 
.. controls +(-45:1) and +(178:1) .. (4.7,-2.8) node[above]{$S$};
\path[name path=hori] (S2) -- ++ (-5,0);
\path[name intersections={of=Xp and hori,by=p}];

\draw[very thick,-latex,postaction={decorate},shorten >= 3pt] (p)
node[above]{$p$} -- node[midway,right] {$\partial_t$} ++ (0,-0.9) 
coordinate[label={[yshift=-3pt]right:$m$}](m);
\draw[very thick,-latex,shorten >= 3pt] (p) -- ++(-0.6,-0.6) 
coordinate[label={[yshift=-3pt]left:$z$}] (z);

\draw pic [fill=black!50] {angle = z--p--m};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I am wondering how much you insist on using `tkz-euclide` here. Without it there would be no problem to also load the `babel` and `quotes` libraries, which will allow you to write an angle without pain. (You can do that with `tkz-euclide`, too, but there might be a point where it becomes impractical.)